# Where, if any, should commas be appropriately placed in a sentence using the phrase "and from there"?

Tags: commas

For instance, if the sentence was something along the lines of:

"I wanted to take the train to your place and from there Uber to the venue."

Would that be fine as is, or is there a comma or two that I'm missing? Does it make a difference if this sentence was lengthier? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It would be preferable to see it written as:

> "I wanted to take the train to your place and, from there, Uber to the venue."

The reason is because "from there" can be taken out and the sentence would still flow perfectly:

> "I wanted to take the train to your place and Uber to the venue."

Since we already know that you're going to be at their place, it would be safe to place commas around repeated information. Depending on which parts of your sentence were to become longer and if said changes turn it into a run-on sentence, adding extra commas would definitely be necessary.

Comment: If the author intentionally didn't use commas, then, syntactically, *from there* ***cannot*** be removed without altering the intended meaning. The use of commas signifies that something is nonrestrictive; the *lack* of commas signifies that it *is* restrictive. You are imposing your own interpretation on the sentence (presuming that *from there* is nonrestrictive), and making a judgment about the commas. But if the author intends *from there* to ***actually*** be restrictive (which it can be), then adding commas would be wrong.